# Is there a way to link a subtask to 2 User stories in Jira GreenHopper?

Tags: jira, greenhopper

I'd like to be able to link a subtask to 2 different user stories. Couldn't find any such option easily available in the config screens ..
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the "Theme/Epic" field on the sub-tasks, you can add the issue keys for both of the user stories to that field (their actually labels).  Then from any GreenHopper view, you can click on the hyperlinked issue-keys in the Theme/Epic field to bring up a dialog of the user story and all associated issues & sub-tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.
A subtask has a single parent issue.

An alternative approach is to use the issue linking feature JIRA provides and link the two stories with a single task to execute.   There are a lot of benefits of doing so, as you can separate out work from specifications.

Check out a description how you can actually gear up your JIRA projects @
http://www.idalko.com/display/WIC/Separation+of+specifications+and+tasks

Francis